# Cant unload NVidia kernel modules on 17.10

Tags: drivers, kernel, nvidia-optimus

On 17.04 everything worked fine. I can switch between gfx cards with `prime-select`. It requires logout-login routine but works. In 17.10 I have issue with that. Switching from Intel to Nvidia works ok. After switch, I have to run command:

`sudo systemctl restart display-manager`

When I try back to Intel I can switch it with `prime-select`, I can restart `display-manager` and use Intel gfx but Nvidia modules are still used. I tried to to find what using Nvidia modules but without success.

`$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             45056  3
nvidia_modeset        843776  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              13004800  1 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 i915,nvidia_drm
drm                   356352  26 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper`

I don't know what is using `nvidia_drm` module.

**Update:**
I checked how `optirun` behaves and it is same situation. After quit from program that was run as parameter of `optirun` command, Nvidia modules cant be unloaded.

**Update 2:**
Problem from Update 1 I resolved by fixing path to nvidia-persistentd in systemd service file. Now nvidia-persistentd service starts properly. But this is not solution for main problem.

**Update 3**
Dirty solution is to use magic sysrq combination with E

`RAlt+SysRq+e`

After this, I can unload Nvidia driver but it breaks some system services. Still searching perfect solution...

**Update 4**
I found that dbus service is blocking nvidia_drm module. After killing it I can remove nvidia modules from memory but Gnome not working fully. Even after restart of dbus service.

Comment: What happens when you switch & reboot?

Comment: You mean switch to Intel and reboot? It behaves as expected. Intel gfx is used and Nvidia modules isn't.

Comment: In 17.10 (with gdm3) when switching via nvidia-prime a reboot is always needed unlike previous Ubuntu releases (lightdm) where a log out/in was good enough

Comment: But in one way it works fine (Intel->Nvidia). No reboot needed. I think that some service is still using this module. I will try trial and error method to find this service.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar issues, where my Nvidia card is keeping my Arch/Ubuntu (tried both) from giving me a video signal after reactivating from suspend. SSH etc works. This did it for me

```
  sudo rmmod nvidia-drm
  sudo rmmod nvidia-modeset
  sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
  sudo rmmod nvidia
  sudo systemctl start lightdm
```